# Logs missing in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

i'm not an expert in android studio, but until now i was able to do what I need.
Now in some cases my app is crashing some times and I don't no why and I can't find any logs.
I don't used AS for a wile and after the update to 2.3.1, there is no tab (at the AS bottom) with the logs (especially the errors)

The only things i can find is in Debug tab the following lines:

```
04/26 12:58:02: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -p APPNAME PATH\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk 
Split APKs installed
$ adb shell am start -n "APPNAME.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Connecting to APPNAME
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8607', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8607', transport: 'socket'
```

The last line I get after the app crashs.
And in the Android Monitor tab there are a couple of lines like these:

```
04-26 15:05:42.244 3164-3175/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

But i do not use SQLite in my app. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You may not use a database, but `com.google.android.gms` (Google play services) does

Comment: You can try running `adb logcat` yourself in a terminal (assuming its on your PATH)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have selected **Firebase** filter in Android Monitor window. Change it to  **Show only selected application**

[image: change ur filter to this!]